# Syntax Checking with unsupported languages

Tags: syntax, ada

I have some files that have a particular syntax that is similar to ada (not identical though), however I would like to verify the syntax before going and running them. There isn't a compiler for these files, so I can't check them before using them. I tried to use the following:

```
gcc -c -gnats <file>
```

However this says compilation unit expected. I've tried a few variations on this, but to no avail.

I just want to make sure the file is syntactically correct before using it, but I'm not sure how to do it, and I really don't want to write an entire syntax checker just for this.

Is there some way to include an additional unsupported language to gcc without going through a recompile? Also is this simply a file that details to gcc what the syntax constructs are, or what would be entailed? I don't need a full compile, only a syntax check.

Alternately, are there any syntax checkers I can use that I can update an ada syntax check with the small number of changes required for this language?

I've listed Ada as a tag, since the syntax is nearly identical, and finding something that will do ada syntax checking without compiling will be a 90% solution for me.

Comment: Does this ada like syntax/language have a name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try running the files through `gnatchop` first. The GCC Ada compiler is rather unique in that it expects filenames to match up with the main unit names inside the file. That may be what your error message is trying to say.

`gnatchop` will go through any files you give it and write out Ada source files with the appropriate names to make gcc happy (even splitting files into multiple files if needed).

Another option you might be interested in is [OpenToken](http://www.stephe-leake.org/ada/opentoken.html). It is a parser construction toolkit, written in Ada, that allows you to build your own parsers fairly easily. It comes with a syntax recognizer for Ada, so you may just be able to tweak that a bit for your needs.

Comment: While I was waiting, I started looking and found this "antlr" program, but most of the tutorials I'm having a hard time following unfortunately. I'll try to spend some time looking at this OpenToken, to see if it's easier to follow.

Comment: @onaclov2000 - I was afraid of that. "Close" isn't always good enough with parsers. Tell me how OpenToken works out for you. It's actually an old project of mine, but others have been running the project for a few years now.

Comment: @onaclov2000 - BTW: I'm actually a bit of an Antlr fan myself. However, generally for someone who knows what they are doing, its a better idea to just write a lexer and parser by hand. If you *don't* know how to do that properly, you're better off using the easiest tool available (in your case probably OpenToken). Antlr and lex/yacc exist in (IMHO) kind of an unhappy middle ground.

Comment: Does Stack overflow have a messaging system? (other then what we're doing here), I just had a few side questions for ya.